# Why isn't time reversal a Galilean transformation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, time-reversal-symmetry, galilean-relativity

I'm a mathematician learning physics from scratch, starting from Newtonian mechanics. As far as I understand, **Galilean transformations** are defined as transformations of space-time that transform from one inertial frame to another. In turn, an **inertial frame** is a frame of reference in which Newton's first law holds: a body not acted upon by any force will move in linear motion. From those two definitions, it seems like Galilean transformations should be all transformations of space-time that preserve  linear motion.

However, Galilean transformations are then described as compositions of:

- Translations of space and time: $(\mathbf{x}, t)\mapsto(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}_0, t+t_0)$.
- Orthogonal transformations of space: $(\mathbf{x}, t)\mapsto(R\mathbf{x}, t)$ where $R:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is an orthogonal transformation. Note that it includes both **rotations** and **reflections** of space.
- Rectilinear motion: $(\mathbf{x}, t)\mapsto(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{v}_0, t)$.

All of them definitely preserve linear motion, but they are not the only ones. We also have:

- Linear transformation of space: $(\mathbf{x}, t)\mapsto(T\mathbf{x}, t)$ where $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ is an invertible linear transformation.
- Time stretching: $(\mathbf{x}, t)\mapsto(\mathbf{x}, at)$, $a>0$.
- Time reversal: $(\mathbf{x}, t)\mapsto(\mathbf{x}, -t)$.

I see why the first two are problematic: they do not preserve measurements of distances and time intervals (so the definition of galilean transformations should really mention that too...). But **what's wrong with time inversion**? It doesn't seem to be any more "problematic" than reflections of space. Both preserve quantitative measurements but invert the orientation.

Comment: I don't think this question is well-defined, since different sources define "Galilean transformation" differently. E.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) accepts only rotations and *not* reflections for $R$. Sources can differ in this because in the end it rarely matters whether reflections and time inversions are included or not. Do you have a specific problem where it *would* matter?

Comment: The Galilean transform has no problem in time reversion in Newtonian mechanics. The deficiency of Galilean transform is failed in observing the equivalent principle for the Maxwell equation.

Comment: Is time inversion and reflections even included in other formalisms (like special relativity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly seems inconsistent to include spatial reflections but at the same time to exclude time reversal.

One reason for excluding *both* spatial reflections and time reversal from the definition (the convention followed in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation), for example) is that this means the topological group of Galilean transformations has a single connected component.